# Questions about Hilbert polynomials.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of projective dimension $d$ and $p_X(t)=(1-t)^{d+1}h(t)$, where $h(t)$ is the Hilbert series of the homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$. Are there some references about the proof of the following theorem? 
If $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is zero-dimensional. Then $p_X(t) \in 1 + t\mathbb{N}[t]$? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Take two points in $\Bbb P^2$, then you have $h(t) = 2$ and so $p_X(t) = (1-t)2 \notin 1 + t \Bbb N[t]$. In fact, one has always $p_X(t) \in 1 - t \Bbb N[t]$ as the Hilbert polynomial of $r$ points is $r$.

Comment: @N.H., thank you very much. Why the Hilbert series $h(t)=r$ when $X$ is $r$ points? I think that $h(t)$ should depend on $t$.

Comment: This is not really true sorry. But for disjoint $X,Y$ one has $h_{X \sqcup Y}(t) = h_X(t) + h_Y(t)$ for $t \gg 0$ and $h_{pt}(t) = 1$. This shows that $h(t) = r$ for $t \gg 0$. But you are right, this is not always true, for example if we take $0$ and $\infty$ in $\Bbb P^1$, we have $h_X(t) = 2$ for $t \geq 1$ and $h_X(t) = 1$ for $t = 0$. You can look the notes of Gathman about Hilbert serie which are very clear.

Comment: @LJR If the homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$ is reduced (however, I don't know if you use this convention), then it is Cohen-Macaulay provided $d=0$. Or for Cohen-Macaulay modules the coefficients of that polynomial are non-negative; see Bruns and Herzog, Corollary 4.1.10.

Comment: @N.H., thank you very much.

Comment: @user26857, thank you very much.

Comment: @user26857, I think that your comment answered my question. Maybe you can write it as an answer?